# Changing Url parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change URL parameters based on which button I click on. Here I set up some javascript to change what the screen displayed depending on which button was clicked:

```
<script language="Javascript">
    //How many Questions 
    function Questions(){
       document.getElementById("Questions").style.visibility="visible";
       document.getElementById("Manual").style.visibility="hidden";
       document.getElementById("Load").style.visibility="hidden";
    }
    //Manual
    function Manual(){
       document.getElementById("Questions").style.visibility="hidden";
       document.getElementById("Manual").style.visibility="visible";
       document.getElementById("Load").style.visibility="hidden";  
    }

    //Load Data from Form
    function Load(){
        document.getElementById("Questions").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("Manual").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("Load").style.visibility="visible";   
    }
</script>


<!--VT Buttons-->
<div id="enterDataToggle" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" >

<!--VT Defualt-->
<label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label"
     <input type="radio" checked onClick="Questions()">
     Default
</label>

<!--VT Input Data Manually-->
<label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label"
    <input type="radio" onClick="Manual()">
        Input Data Manually
</label>

<!--VT Load Data from File-->
<label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label"
    <input type="radio" onClick="Load()">
        Load Data from File
    </label>
```

And here is where I am setting my URL parameters:

```
            <!--VT How many Questions-->
            <div style="position:absolute" id="Questions" >
                <h4>How many questions were on the ballot?</h4>
                <input name="votingDist" type="radio" value="-1"=> Short: 1-3 questions<br>
                <input name="votingDist" type="radio" value="0"> Medium: 4+ qustions<br>
                <input name="VTMean" value="61.11"; style= "visibility:hidden;" type="text" style="width:100%">
                <input name="VTMean" value="128.69"; style= "visibility:hidden;" type="text" style="width:100%">
                <input name="VTStd" value="-1"; style= "visibility:hidden;" type="text" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <!-- VT Input Data Manually--> 
           <!--CT Default-->
            <div style=" visibility:hidden; position:absolute" id="Manual" >
                <input name="votingDist" value="1"; style= "visibility:hidden;" type="text" style="width:100%">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                Mean
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Standard Deviation
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                 <input name="VTMean" type="text" style="width:100%">
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                 <input name="VTStd" type="text" style="width:100%">
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>


            <!-- Load Data from File--> 
            <div style="visibility:hidden; position:relative" id="Load">
                <h4>Load Data from File</h4>
                <input name="arrivalFile" type="file" name="fileField"><br>
            </div>
```

The problem is my URL's are coming out with repeated parameters : http://localhost:8080/CrunchifyJSPServletExample/CrunchifyServlet?votingDist=-1&VTMean=61.11&VTMean=128.69&VTStd=-1&votingDist=1&VTMean=200&VTStd=20

I am trying to find a way to replace the value of the parameter when a different button is clicked. Is there a way to do this? Any help is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: We cannot access your localhost :), make a fiddle.

Comment: Where is the code that adds url parameters?

Comment: Try this code please. http://cwestblog.com/2013/05/21/javascript-modify-url-parameters/

Comment: Just saw these while reading your code. There are couple of duplicate parameters in there. Make sure your name elements are change from other elements please. ex: votingDist = -1 and 0 in your html code. So when the form submits it's going to repeat the values in there. Get the necessary information from server side if you have unique element names.

Comment: Your input fields share the same names which is why they are included twice. Changing their visibility is not going to prevent them from being submitted. In Questions(), Manual(), and Load() try adding and removing the elements from the form rather than changing the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object and set the properties. So if you set again it will override the value. Then you can convert it to url parameters format:

```
var params = {};

params['votingDist'] = -1;
params['votingDist'] = 2;

params['VTMean'] = 200;
params['VTMean'] = 300;

var urlParamsToSet = Object.keys(params)
  .reduce((a, b) => `${a}${a ? '&' : '?'}${b}=${params[b]}`, '');
// ?votingDist=2&VTMean=300
```

Then use `urlParamsToSet` to change the url.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do, but how would I use this in my code? I have tried putting it in javascript takes but I cannot get it to add anything to the URL. Thanks for your help!